# Dynamic scheduler in Liferay 7.0

Tags: cron, liferay, liferay-7

I need to build a module that lets the user to set scheduling for the several tasks with custom triggers. User can schedule/unschedule/modify jobs dynamically.
The way from version 6.2 does not work anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Check this example
https://github.com/liferay/liferay-blade-samples/tree/master/liferay-workspace/modules/blade.schedulerentry

Key Points
 its a service now & Need to extend BaseSchedulerEntryMessageListener

```
@Component(immediate = true, service = BladeSchedulerEntryMessageListener.class)
public class BladeSchedulerEntryMessageListener
    extends BaseSchedulerEntryMessageListener {

    @Activate
    @Modified
    protected void activate() {
        schedulerEntryImpl.setTrigger(
            TriggerFactoryUtil.createTrigger(
                getEventListenerClass(), getEventListenerClass(), 15,
                TimeUnit.MINUTE));

        _schedulerEngineHelper.register(
            this, schedulerEntryImpl, DestinationNames.SCHEDULER_DISPATCH);
    }

    @Deactivate
    protected void deactivate() {
        _schedulerEngineHelper.unregister(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doReceive(Message message) throws Exception {
        if (_log.isInfoEnabled()) {
            _log.info("Received message on schedule: " + message);
        }
    }

    private final Log _log = LogFactoryUtil.getLog(
        BladeSchedulerEntryMessageListener.class);

    @Reference(target = ModuleServiceLifecycle.PORTAL_INITIALIZED, unbind = "-")
    private volatile ModuleServiceLifecycle _moduleServiceLifecycle;

    @Reference(unbind = "-")
    private volatile SchedulerEngineHelper _schedulerEngineHelper;

    @Reference(unbind = "-")
    private volatile TriggerFactory _triggerFactory;

}
```

Comment: I've seen this example, but I have no idea how to start and stop a task and change schedule time dynamically.

Comment: @Alex You might want to rephrase your question from "does not work anymore" to what you actually tried, what works, what doesn't and what you actually want to do/know/achieve. Probably nobody will be able to give you the information you're looking for if you only provide random snippets and reveal more and more details later once someone has taken the steps to help you.